# MediaPlayer not playing when attaching BassBoost - error (-22, 0)

Tags: java, android, audio, effects, android-mediaplayer

It should be simple as this:

```
private void startPlaying() {
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);

        BassBoost bassBoost = new BassBoost(0, mPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
        mPlayer.attachAuxEffect(bassBoost.getId());
        bassBoost.setStrength((short)1000);
        bassBoost.setEnabled(true);
        mPlayer.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);

        mPlayer.prepare();

        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mPlayer.start();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
        }
```

When I try, it is quiet and I get the error (-22,0) in the log. If I comment the lines between `BassBoost bassBoost = ...` and `mPlayer.setAuxEffectSendLevel` it plays the sound OK.

I went though documentation, but I cant fidn the error. Permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: Have you got any answer or solution regarding this? or implementing BassBooster in Media Player ?

Comment: Actually I didn't get find a solution. I did my effect with `SoundPool`.

Comment: yes Soundpool in nice one. But how to do same with the mediaPlayer? Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, no. I was happy with SoundPool :)

Comment: Ok. thanks for the comment. And answer here if you found any solution regarding that.

Comment: So you have implemented soundpool for whole music app? or just for Bass Effect ?

Comment: I have implemented just SoundPool.

Answer (score 2):

You are already attached your bassboost with your mediaplayer when it created. So remove this line`mPlayer.attachAuxEffect(bassBoost.getId());`

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would explanation be best if you could provide some for why it does so.

Comment: As far as I can tell: calling `attachAuxEffect` adds it to a list of effects. If that effect is already in the list, it causes an error. The way this shows up in `MediaPlayer` is that the `OnErrorListener` is invoked. I saw this myself and it wasn't until this answer that I was able to figure it out. Secondarily, I think keeping a reference to the `BassBoost` is required but I haven't verified that

Answer (score 0):

Yep, remove the method `attachAuxEffect` from the media player class, I mean this `linemPlayer.attachAuxEffect(bassBoost.getId());`

Secondly you can call `bass boost` object at any state of the media player excluding the idle state